# Override-equivalent signatures in Java, why are compile-time errors restricted to this condition in the Java Language Specification?

Tags: java

The Java Language Specification (Java SE 7 Edition to be exact) [states the following](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.

The specification does not state that it is a compile-time error to declare two methods with the *same* signature in terms of the following definition:

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.

So, with this, the following class should not compile since as far as I can tell the two getters are not override-equivalent:

```
public class Foo {

private String value = null;

public Foo(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

String getValue() {
    System.out.println("String version");
    return value;
}

int getValue() {
    System.out.println("int version");
    return Integer.parseInt(value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo("5");
    System.out.println(foo.getValue());
    System.out.println(foo.getValue() + 5);
}

}
```

My question is this, is this not an oversight in the Java Language Specification? Surely class Foo should not compile?

My IDE complains, but my compiler does not. In addition, when the main method runs, the order in which the getters are declared changes the output.

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, my .class files where produced by the Eclipse Compiler for Java. I had no idea that [it can produce .class files even in the face of compilation errors](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-java-builder.htm) and hence was baffled.

Comment: Does not compiles with latest SDK (JDK 7u45)

Comment: I get a "Duplicate Method" compilation error.

Comment: I tried it with 6u45, 7u7, 7u45, and 8b118, and got the same "error: method getValue() is already defined" in every case. It could have been a short-lived bug that escaped into 7u11, or something is wonky in your environment.

Comment: @Nico Which platform do you use?

Comment: As it turns out, the Eclipse Compiler for Java was producing the class file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presented class should not compile in terms of the Java Language Specification, and it does not compile with for example the latest JDKu45 on Windowsx64 because as pointed out in the question having two methods in a class that have the same signature constitutes a compile-time error.

Although the class should not compile in terms of the Java Language Specification, this does not mean that you will not see the class compiling. This is because for example the [Eclipse Compiler for Java produces .class files in the face of compilation errors](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-java-builder.htm) and with the provided example class it will both compile and run the program.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't compile. The return value type is not one of the arguments. The virtual machine cannot determine which method you meant, because it doesn't care about what you do with the return value.

[Quote from 8.2. Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)

> For a method, an ordered 3-tuple consisting of:
>
> ```
> - argument types: a list of the types of the arguments to the method member.
> - return type: the return type of the method member.
> - throws clause: exception types declared in the throws clause of the method member.
> ```

In combination with your quotes of the Java specification:

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.

and

> It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with
>   override-equivalent signatures in a class.

this requires a compile-time error, so it's an oversight of the compiler.

Comment: even i also agree specification. but finding reason how JVM not behaving as per specification

Answer (score 0):

I get this with JDK 7u45 (Windows x64):

```
foo.java:14: error: method getValue() is already defined in class Foo
int getValue() {
    ^
1 error
```

Probably you comparing latest specs and old compiler version.

Either update your compiler or find old specs ;)

Ideone: [link](http://ideone.com/Lg9rt8)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should read on the link you provided:

> 1. Two methods have the same signature if they have **the same name and argument types**.
> 2. The signature of a method m1 is a **subsignature** of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
>    1. **m2 has the same signature as m1**, or
>    2. the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.
>
> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are **override-equivalent** iff either m1
>   is a **subsignature** of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.
>
> **It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.**

So, if two methods have the same signature (which has nothing to do with return type), their signatures are subsignatures of each other. This makes them override-equivalent, which yields a compilation error.

In your case, both `getValue` methods have the same signature, which makes them override-equivalent, which makes the class illegal. Any proper java compiler should not compile that kind of code.